# php how using array in if clause

Tags: php

Use this associative array to generate a mysql where clause.

```
$arr = array(’catid_1’ => ‘1’, ‘catid_2’ => ‘’, 'catid_3' => '45', catid_4 => '10', count=>'1');

$var = 'catid_1';
$var2 = 'catid_2';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
{
   if(($value <> '') && ($key <> 'count'))
   {
    if ($key == $var)
    {
        $whr[] = "(" . $var . " = '" . $value . "' OR resid = '2')"; 
    }
    elseif ($key == $var2)
    {
        $whr[] = "(" . $var2 . " = '" . $value . "' OR resid = '2')"; 
    } 
    else    
    {
        $whr[] = $key . "='" . $value . "'";
    }
   } 
}
```

I would like to do the same thing using in place of var1 and var2 the data contained in an array like this.

```
$arr2 = array('catid_1', 'catid_2', 'catid_7');
```

how could I do if clauses? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

```
if(in_array('find element',$arr2)){
// code
}
```

in this function first element shows wheat we trying to find and 2nd element is array in which we are trying to match 1st element.

this function iterate a loop operation and match our string or element to every element in array. and at first when any match occur it return `true`

Comment: why -1? I tried with in_array and it seems perfect. What's the problem?

Comment: While I'm not the downvoter, you're generally expected to provide some context (explain **how** it works) for the benefit of later readers.

Comment: @PaoloRossi if you found exactly you want. you can mark as Answer. #mabi Thank you for kind suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_search function  to serve your purpose.
for syntax refer to [Array Search](https://www.php.net/array_search)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring $whr as an array before you start adding values to it.

I.e. Add '$whr=array();' where you declare $var1 and $var2.